Does bittorrent dht have a way to guarantee new message types work across unsupported peers?
Im reading bittorrent dht extension 44 and want to make a new extension similar to the get/put messages but to save multiple values at the same hash and with a different verification algorithm, but looking at the bep44 extension document i see a problem where introducing a new message type doesn't guarantee that the message will work because you can't guarantee that the peers you are connected to supports this message, so the peer will simply drop the message.
Since there is no mechanism for peers to advertise the extensions they support and since there is no mechanism that bootstraps the dht buckets with peers that support these extensions, then if my node's buckets get filled with peers that don't support my extension(which is entirely possible since most peers will have default dht or popular extensions only) then  the messages will simply drop

Yes, see the forward compatibility section in libtorrent docs:
https://www.libtorrent.org/dht_extensions.html#forward-compatibility

In order to support future DHT messages, any message which is not recognized but has either an info_hash or target argument is interpreted as find node for that target. i.e. it returns nodes.


This will not guarantee compatibility, it is very possible that every peer returned doesn't support this message, because it just happened that all the peers that support this message have a distant peer hash

Nothing in the DHT is "guaranteed". You're dealing with an open, distributed system with many implementations that have added features over the years. Some peers are even malicious and violate the basic specs. So your expectations are too high. You'll have to work with what's available.
